# Problems installing gmp-6.1.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, packages

I'm trying to install gmp on a server.

Running:

> ```
> autoreconf -i -f
> ./configure --prefix=/home/myusername/mydirectory
> make
> ```

produces after a wall of text:

> ```
> ...
> .libs/assert.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> make[2]: *** [libgmp.la] Error 1
> make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/myusername/mydirectory/gmp-6.1.2'
> make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
> make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/myusername/mydirectory/gmp-6.1.2'
> make: *** [all] Error 2
> ```

I have no idea what that signifies and googling didn't help me yet. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I copied the gmp-folder directly onto the server. Instead I had to put the gmp-tar-file on the server and untar it there. Now it seems to work.